# Django background RabbitMQ Connection

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, amqp

Alright, so I have a somewhat unique issue that I'm dealing with. I'm writing a small web application in Django and I would like it to interface with RabbitMQ *directly* over the backend. IE, I have a server task that I'm developing a web interface for, and I want to interact with it's API directly through the Message Queue. I'm struggling with how to spawn a long-running connection to the Message Queue. To state the obvious, it's expensive to construct/teardown TCP connections to RMQ for every new request! So, is it possible to create some long-running process that I can use to interact with this AMQP API?

As a note regarding Celery, since I'm sure it will be mentioned, my understanding of Celery is that it is great at distributing time-intensive tasks to other processes and/or nodes, but does not expose a long-running AMQP connection to the Django application. So I don't think it will help here. That being said, I also haven't done much more than the tutorial and read parts of the documentation.

Comment: I have had success with a task which took approximately 2 days duration to complete using celery and RabbitMQ.

Comment: I wouldn't doubt it. Celery is an awesome piece of technology. The reason it doesn't work in this situation is that I need to interface directly with the Message Queue itself. IE, I already have an existing backend that has an API exposed through AMQP. Celery *does* integrate with AMQP for offloading tasks, but it doesn't let me touch the queue directly, since it's handling all the work. I ended up resolving this through multiprocessing and a couple of thin wrappers around pika.

Comment: The question isn't clear. What's the exact issue you faced? I have processes running for days interacting directly with RabbitMQ and never had any problems with long-running connections. You shouldn't need to construct/teardown TCP connections for every request if you use Kombu and connection pool.

Comment: By the way, celery doesn't expose the connection directly, but you can reach it from the main celery instance if you want/need it. I do that for sending stats and logs from workers to a central consumer.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue with you. How did you solve this problem?